# manifest.json file not being read by Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, manifest, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

My pages have this line in them to point to the manifest.json file:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="https://www.seekadventure.net/manifest.json">
```

You can see in the chrome console here it is not being recognized:

[image]

Are their special permissions etc that need to be set on the manifest.json file?

Comment: Does your manifest file and the index.html in the same location? Are those located in the specified static url?

Comment: wouldn't pointing right at the manifest file like so work for that though: href="https://www.seekadventure.net/manifest.json"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting `<link rel="manifest" href="https://www.seekadventure.net/manifest.json">`
inside the `<head>` tags.